# Headers linking - PlatformIO

Tags: compile

For those who use the IDE Platform IO, I have an issue for you. I use to program a home application of sensor reading and use the library "JC_Button.h" to manage buttons. There are other third-party libraries, but this in especial is cumbersome. The project tree is shown below.

[image: project-tree].

The compile log of the build is [here](http://codepad.org/x3uVz30U). I have few notion of what is happening. In my opinion, the project does not find the necessary lib.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your log file says the compiler can’t find the header file. check that the include dir exists and that the compiler knows how to find it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not telling PlatformIO that you need the JC_Button library. Try adding this to your `platformio.ini` file:

```
lib_deps = https://github.com/JChristensen/JC_Button
```